# How to refresh the login window when I'm closing the main window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm creating a small admin application using WPF. It has two windows; login window and main window. The login window is, of course, just username and password. And the main window shows data from the DB. The problem is; when I log in, the main window opens, and because of animations on the log in window, both the username and the password disappears. How can I refresh the log in window when I close the main window? Thanks!

The code for the login screen;

```
public partial class LoginScreen : Window
{
    public LoginScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Verify hashed password
    public static bool VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string password)
    {

        byte[] buffer4;
        if (hashedPassword == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (password == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
        }
        byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(hashedPassword);
        if ((src.Length != 0x31) || (src[0] != 0))
        {
            return false;
        }
        byte[] dst = new byte[0x10];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 1, dst, 0, 0x10);
        byte[] buffer3 = new byte[0x20];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0x11, buffer3, 0, 0x20);
        using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes bytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, dst, 0x3e8))
        {
            buffer4 = bytes.GetBytes(0x20);
        }
        return ByteArraysEqual(buffer3, buffer4);
    }

    private static bool ByteArraysEqual(byte[] buffer3, byte[] buffer4)
    {
        bool areEqual = buffer3.SequenceEqual(buffer4);

        return areEqual;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection
        {
            ConnectionString = "server=db.***.**;database=***;uid=***;pwd=***;"
        };


        MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT brukernavn, passord FROM admin_user WHERE brukernavn = '" + txtUsername.Text + "' AND passord ='" + txtPassword.Password + "'";

        conn.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        String dbUsername = string.Empty;
        String dbPassword = string.Empty;


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            dbUsername += reader.GetString("brukernavn");
            dbPassword += reader.GetString("passord");

        }

        if (dbUsername == "" || dbPassword == "") 
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Wrong username and Password");
            string message = "Wrong username or password";
            string title = "Error";
            MessageBox.Show(message, title);

            this.Show();
            LoginScreen mm = new LoginScreen();
            mm.Show();
        }
        else 
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Success");

            this.Show();
            MainWindow mm = new MainWindow();
            mm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

And this is the code for the main window;

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { }


    private void Show_Users_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection
        {
            ConnectionString = "server=db.****.**;database=***;uid=***;pwd=***;"
        }; try
        {
            conn.Open();





            string Query = "SELECT accountId, level, email, name FROM account";

            MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);



            createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


            MySqlDataAdapter dataAdp = new MySqlDataAdapter(createCommand);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("account");
            dataAdp.Fill(dt);
            EditUsers.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            dataAdp.Update(dt);
            conn.Close();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    private void Edit_Data_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection
        {
            ConnectionString = "server=db.****.**;database=***;uid=***;pwd=***;"
        }; try
        {
            conn.Open();





            string Query = "SELECT accountId, level, email, name FROM account ";

            MySqlCommand createCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);



            createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


            MySqlDataAdapter dataAdp = new MySqlDataAdapter(createCommand);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("account");
            dataAdp.Fill(dt);
            EditUsers.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            dataAdp.Update(dt);
            conn.Close();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There you go, I've updated my question with the code.

Comment: Why aren't you just closing the loginwindow once they log in? Make the ….errm… other window Application.Current.MainWindow so your app doesn't shut down. And. Why do you need to refresh the login window. What exactly do you mean by refresh?

Comment: That's a good point. I'll probably go for that. Removing the login window once the users are logged in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`LoginScreen` in this you need to close LoginScreen screen

```
       else 
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Success");
            this.Close();
            MainWindow mm = new MainWindow();
            mm.Show();
        }
```